# jenkins pipeline def new string parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized job with pipeline.
for example: Predefined String Parameter: **IP**
I'm trying to define a new String in the pipeline in order to use it as a new parameter when I'm calling to another "build job"

I have tried the following method:

```
import hudson.model.*
node('master'){
if(ipaddr =='192.168.1.1'){
    def parameter = new StringParameterValue("subnet", '255.255.255.0') //not working
    echo parameter //not working
}

stage ('Stage A'){
    build job: 'jobA', parameters:
 [
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ip', value: ip],
  [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'subnet', value: subnet] //not working
 ]
}
}
```

this way it's not working and I get the error:

> Scripts not permitted to use new hudson.model.StringParameterValue

after changing the line:

```
def parameter = new StringParameterValue("subnet", '255.255.255.0')
```

to:

```
subnet = '255.255.255.0'
```

I got the error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: subnetmask for
>   class: groovy.lang.Binding.

I can't call to a new job with the predefined parameter **ip** and the new parameter **subnet**

without the **subnet** it's working

any idea of how can I define new String parameter in the pipeline?

jenkins version: 2.19.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have it working if you just avoid instantiating `StringParameterValue` because as David M. Karr mentionned pipelines sandbox is pretty restrictive. Instead, just use your simple variable when calling your job, like this :

```
def subnet = ""
if(ipaddr == '192.168.1.1') {
    subnet = '255.255.255.0'
    echo subnet
}

stage ('Stage A'){
    build job: 'jobA', parameters:
    [
        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ip', value: ipaddr],
        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'subnet', value: subnet]
    ]
}
```

It's pretty simple, StringParameterValue params expect String to be passed, so as long as you pass string values you should be just fine !

Comment: Thanks @Pom12 but I got the error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: subnetmask for class: groovy.lang.Binding. any idea?

Comment: Can you please edit your initial post to reflect what you are now trying ?

Comment: From what I see, you've called you variable `subnet` but try to pass a `subnetmask` variable as a parameter... make sure your naming is correct

Answer (score 0):

By default, the sandbox the pipeline job executes in is very restricted.  You have to override the security restrictions when you find them.  Go to "Manage Jenkins" and "In-process Script Approval". You should see in the list the last violation that occurred.  Select it for approval and rerun your script.

Comment: Thanks @David M. Karr .. Do you know if this is the only way to create new parameters in a pipeline?

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to add parameters to a downstream pipeline, within the code of a pipeline job. Adding parameters to a pipeline job is simple. I have no idea how to add parameters to a downstream pipeline job.