# Dynamically evaluate default in Jenkins pipeline build parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins declarative pipeline we can define build parameters like

```
pipeline {
    …
    parameters {
        string(name: 'PARAMETER', defaultValue: 'INITIAL_DEFAULT')
        choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: ['THIS', 'THAT'])
    }
    …
}
```

However the parameter definitions of the job are only updated when the job runs *after* the build parameters dialog was already shown. That is, when I change the `INITIAL_DEFAULT` to something else, the next build will still default to `INITIAL_DEFAULT` and only the one after that will use the new value.

The same problem is with the `choices`, and there it is even more serious, because string default can be overwritten easily when starting the build, but if the new option isn't there, it cannot be selected at all.

So is there a way to define functions or expressions that will be executed before the parameter dialog to calculate current values (from files, variable in global settings or any other suitable external configuration)?

I remember using some plugins for this in the past with free-style jobs, but searching the plugin repository I can't find any that would mention how to use it with pipelines.

I don't care too much that the same problem applies to adding and removing parameters, because that occurs rarely. But we have some parameters where the default changes often and we need the next nightly to pick up the updated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the [extended-choice-parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter) does work with pipeline, and the configurations can be generated by the directive generator. It looks something like

```
extendedChoice(
    name: 'PARAMETER',
    type: 'PT_TEXTBOX',
    defaultPropertyFile: '/var/lib/jenkins/something.properties',
    defaultPropertyKey: 'parameter'
)
```

(there are many more options available in the generator)

Groovy script to get global environment variables can be had from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088936/jenkins-pipeline-def-new-string-parameter).